# C++ STL set: Can I use upper_bound() to find the minimum difference of a number with the elements of the set?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I am working on a problem. I have a number `a` and a set of elements (say `myset`). I want to find the number `b` in `myset` such that `|b-a|` is minimum. I am using `it=upper_bound(a)` and then check `|*it-a|` and `|(*it-1)-a|` and take the minimum of these two. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: You want to find the absolute value of the difference between `a` and the contents of your set, where the absolute value will be the minimum?  Seems you only would need the largest and smallest entries of your set then (`myset.begin()`, `myset.rbegin()`).

Comment: @Abhay Mittal If number a is present in the set do you have to select some its neighbour?

Comment: @Chad That wont work because I need to find the element closest to a and then calculate the difference to get the minimum. In your case, the value might not be the minimum value.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow No. I will output 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct except for the edge cases: what if `upper_bound` returns `end()` and what if it returns `begin()`?

```
// pre-conditions: contains at least 1 elem, is sorted

template <typename It, typename Value>
const Value& min_dist(It first, It last, const Value& a)
{
    It it = std::upper_bound(first, last, a);
    if (it == last) {
        return *(std::prev(last, 1));
    }
    else if (it == first) {
        return *it;
    }
    else {
        // somewhere in the middle, so both it and prev are valid
        It prev = std::prev(it, 1);
        return (*it - a) < (a - *prev)
            ? *it : *prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barry! That did solve my problem :D I was checking the boundary conditions but was not initializing minimum to INT_MAX in my code (I was comparing with multiple values of a and finding global minimum). 

Can't upvote because I dont have enough reputation.